# DeviceMotion event in javascript for the mobile web

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, mobile-safari

I have been all over the web trying to figure out how to use the devicemotion event in javascript to capture the accelerometer on mobile safari for the iPad or the iPhone. I just would like to know how can i implement it into a website or if somewone could please give me a good explanation of how it works thanks

Comment: http://cubiq.org/device-motion-websockets-node-js-tech-demo

Answer (score 2):

iOS supports the [DeviceOrientation](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source-orientation.html) API.

Here's a sample: http://www.mobilexweb.com/samples/ball.html

Comment: I have seen this example before and i understand the event caller, but the part i am confused at is; say i have a n image on the screen and each time the user tilts the device i want the image to slide in that direction but on from right to left, not just anywhere. how would i go about doing that. thanks